# Triângulo Delphi - Canvas

Tags: delphi, canvas

Quero desenhar um triângulo no Delphi por meio do `Canvas`.

Esse ponteiro servirá como um ponteiro de um `Gauge` (Speedometer) como neste exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Utilizo o `TPoint()` para definir onde o ponteiro apontará. Sei o ponto inicial, mas a minha dificuldade está em rotacionar o triângulo para ângulo correto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Descobri!

Segue a lógica matemática:

```
  x01 := Round(x0 * (1 - Cos(Angle)));
  y01 := Round((R.Bottom - 1) * (1 - Sin(Angle)));
  x02 := Round( x0 + radiusS * Cos(2 * pi / 3 + Angle) );
  y02 := Round( y0 + radiusS * Sin(2 * pi / 3 + Angle) );
  x03 := Round( x0 + radiusS * Cos(4 * pi / 3 + Angle) );
  y03 := Round( y0 + radiusS * Sin(4 * pi / 3 + Angle) );
  Polygon([Point(x01,y01),Point(x02,y02),Point(x03,y03)]);
```

Legenda:

- x01 e y01: São os pontos da base do triângulo, ou seja, da menor reta
  do triângulo;
- x0 e R.Bottom: É o ponto inicial do triângulo, o ponto de partida
  para a menor linha do triângulo.
- x02, y02, x03 e y03: São os pontos das duas retas maiores do
  triângulo, que formarão o ângulo final do mesmo;
- Angle: Ângulo no qual o triângulo deverá estar apontando;
- RadiusS: Tamanho das retas maiores, que formarão o ângulo do
  triângulo;

PS: Todas as variáveis devem ser do tipo Double.

Answer (score 3):

Para Rotacionar tente:

Aqui eu vou criar um triangulo no próprio formulário:

```
Form1.Canvas.Polygon([Point(20, 10), Point(10, 50), Point(80, 30)]);
```

Vai alterando os `Point` e vendo os resultados, vai precisar de uma boa Lógica Matemática para conseguir atingir o resultado com maiores perfeições, observe que você precisara manipular 6 variáveis para ter total controle!

Comment: Agradeço a iniciativa, mas o que eu precisava era da lógica matemática. Já a postei na resposta do tópico.

Obrigado.